# batch script to read text separated by delimiter

Tags: file, windows-7, batch-file

I have a text file which contains a list of URLs separated by comma. 
e.g. URL1,URL2,URL3 etc.

I have a batch script which just launches the url in the text file.

```
for /f "delims=," %%a in (ListOfURLs.txt) do (start /wait iexplore.exe %%a)
```

Currently, it only launches the 1st URL and stops. It is not reading the subsequent URLs.
Help needed.

Comment: that's because of the `start /wait ` - it waits until the browser is closes.Try without `wait`

Answer (score 4):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR /f "delims=" %%u IN (listofurls.txt) DO (
 FOR %%i IN (%%u) DO ECHO START iexplore %%i
)
```

the `ECHO` is to show what is intended. To execute, remove the `ECHO` keyword.

Comment: @peter Thanks a lot. It solves the purpose, but with `/wait` switch. I wonder why `"delims=,"` doesn't work?

Comment: For/f works on one LINE at a time. By default, it returns the first token to the metavariable (`%%a` in your version). If you want the remaining tokens, you need to specify `"tokens-1-12"` where `12` is simply an example - it is the maximum number of tokens in the line. These tokens will then be returned to `%%a`, `%%b` ... so you'd need to check whether a token was empty before executing the `IEXPLORE`. As I modified it, the entire line in `%%u` is selected item-by-item by `%%i` as the line `%%u` is simply a conventional comma-separated list.